# Schreibweise von Zahladjektiven mit er-Endung

Tags: spelling, numbers

Ich bin mir nie ganz sicher beim Schreiben von Zahladjektiven, die auf *-er* enden:

- eine 10-er Packung / 10er-Packung / Zehnerpackung / etc.
- die S/siebziger Jahre / 70er-Jahre / 70er Jahre / Siebzigerjahre
- etc.

Wie lauten hier die genauen Regeln?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suffixe werden nur dann mit Bindestrich angehängt, wenn vorher ein Einzelbuchstabe steht ([Duden – Regel 30](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich#K30)):

> n-fach; x-te Wurzel

Ansonsten ohne Bindestrich:

> die 68er, 5%ig

Bilden Ziffer+Nachsilbe den ersten Teil einer Zusammensetzung, werden die zusammengesetzten Teile mit Bindestrich verbunden:

> die 68er-Generation

Korrekt ist also: *10er-Packung*, *Zehnerpackung*, *Siebzigerjahre* (die letzten beiden sind m. E. „normale“ Substantive). *70er-Jahre* wäre nach den Bindestrich-Regeln auch möglich (siehe auch [Duden-Beispiel zu Regel 68](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/gross-und-kleinschreibung#K68)), aber dem Substantiv würde ich den Vorzug geben. Laut Duden geht auch *siebziger Jahre* (*siebziger* als Adjektiv, daher klein – vgl. [Duden: *achtziger*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/achtziger)).